# Убрать css атрибут по id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый день. Хочу убрать атрибут со стилей
Вот так выглядит css в style.css:

```
#id1 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Так выглядит мой JS файл:

```
if ($('.class1').length == 0) {
    $('#id1').removeAttr('position');
}
```

И при этом атрибут не исчезает, подскажите пожалуйста почему.

Comment: Потому что `removeAttr` это для HTML-атрибутов, а не для CSS. Вообще, всё прописанное в `style.css` удалить нельзя, только прописать новое значение поверх старого

Comment: А как в данном случае поменять например на position: relative?

Comment: Гугл по запросу "jquery css" первой же ссылкой выдаёт официальную документацию с `.css('position', 'relative')`

Comment: еще как вариант добавить новый класс, в который прописать новые css свойства